# rails: style will_paginate with bootstrap links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, will-paginate

I have a bootstrap style on my will_paginate that i would like to customize!:

[image of my pagination links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ar4y.png)

As you can see on my image, I would like to hide the number of page to only show the previous and next label.

I succeeded to custom the icon of next and previous label like this:
in **config/locales/en.yml:**

```
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: <i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="color:black"></i>
    next_label: <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="color:black"></i>
```

But I am really stuck on the process to hide this labels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

In your view, try the `page_links` option:

```
<%= will_paginate @your_objects, page_links: false %>
```

For more info see the [API documentation for view template helpers](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#view-template-helpers).